# Data isn't passed in post method to api call

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm working on one project with AngularJs(1.5) and Codeigniter rest server. I'm wondering why data tag isn't passed to php? Let me show you my code and explain further with comments.

Factory

```
factory.insert = function(tag){
        console.log(tag); //out put present, so problem is in http request
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/rest/api/tag/tag/',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: {
                tag: tag
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('Can\'t insert tag: ' + response.data.message);
        });
    };
```

PHP

```
public function tag_post()
{
    $condition['tag'] = $this->post('tag');
    var_dump($condition);
}
```

`var_dump $condition['tag']` is 'tag' `null`

**UPDATE**

Small change in factory solved my problem. Now my data looks like this and it works. Why?

```
data: $.param({
   tag: tag
})
```

**UPDATE 2**

Same thing happens if i work with cakePhp or Codeigniter. So i guess it's not a php side problem

Comment: If `tag` is object, so pass it as `data: tag`

Comment: before return success[object Object] happens, so request goes trough, but value in database is NULL. Type of tag var is string

Comment: Is it the same with `headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}` ?

Comment: sadly yes... tag is null... One think that i figure out. If i make request
/rest/api/tag/tag/ +tag, then i can fetch $tag value in php function as incoming function argument.... But i wan't to send this as data, since i don't know what possible chars people will type as tags

Comment: solved and updated question? why this is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data always needs to be set with $.param function, when you are making post request in Angular, so params are "prepared / added".

```
data: $.param({
   tag: tag
})
```

For example in VueJs you would do something like this

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('firstName', this.name);
this.$http.post(this.$apiUrl + `rest/api/User/User/` + id_user, params, {})
```